# yum require an older version of a package as dependency

Tags: fedora, yum, latex

I have installed TexLive 2012 via the [official site](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) and want to install epydoc which depends on an older version.  However, when I try to install epydoc which depends on texlive, I get the below error.

How can I fix this?

```
; sudo yum install epydoc     
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit, remove-
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit, remove-
              : with-leaves
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: ftp.tudelft.nl
 * livna: rpm.livna.org
 * rpmfusion-free: ftp.upjs.sk
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: ftp.upjs.sk
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: ftp.upjs.sk
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: ftp.upjs.sk
 * updates: ftp.tudelft.nl
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package epydoc.noarch 0:3.0.1-9.fc15 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: texlive-latex for package: epydoc-3.0.1-9.fc15.noarch
Package texlive-latex-2007-66.fc16.x86_64 is obsoleted by 1:tex-latex-svn23639-1
.noarch which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: texlive-dvips for package: epydoc-3.0.1-9.fc15.noarch
Package texlive-dvips-2007-66.fc16.x86_64 is obsoleted by 1:tex-dvips-svn26765-1
.noarch which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: epydoc-3.0.1-9.fc15.noarch (fedora)
           Requires: texlive-dvips
           Available: texlive-dvips-2007-65.fc16.x86_64 (fedora)
               texlive-dvips = 2007-65.fc16
           Available: texlive-dvips-2007-66.fc16.x86_64 (updates)
               texlive-dvips = 2007-66.fc16
Error: Package: epydoc-3.0.1-9.fc15.noarch (fedora)
           Requires: texlive-latex
           Available: texlive-latex-2007-65.fc16.x86_64 (fedora)
               texlive-latex = 2007-65.fc16
           Available: texlive-latex-2007-66.fc16.x86_64 (updates)
               texlive-latex = 2007-66.fc16
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You could try using `--skip-broken` to work around the problem
2. Contact the TEX-Developers and report this as bug
3. If you really want to, you can try `yum downgrade`

**Update**: Since `yum --skip-broken` does not work here:

```
yumdonwloader epydoc-3.0.1-9.fc15.noarch
rpm -i --nodeps epydoc-3.0.1-9.fc15.noarch.rpm
```

Should work.

Comment: `--skip-broken` does not install epydoc which kinda defeats the point of installing it.

Comment: By TEX-Developers who do you mean?  Do you mean the package maintainers for latex live or epydoc or both?

Comment: @Sardathrion this seems to be a epydoc-problem. It should be sufficient if the newer version of `tex-dvips` is installed. This has to be coded into the requires-section of the epydoc-rpm.

Comment: @Sardathrion Updated my answer so you can circumvent the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use the packages for Fedora, or use the packages for TeXlibe 2012 from Jindrich Novy's [repo](http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/texlive/). Don't mix, they don't work well together (jnovy's uses other directories, they won't find each other at all).